# SVNKit alternative

Tags: java, svn

Does anyone know of a good Java Subversion library? I'd use SVNKit but it's only open source if the code you're working on is open source.

Comment: As in the discussion on @simbo1905's answer, you need to be clear whether you're talking about (a) using SVNKit to perform SVN operations on some (non-open-source) code (presumably in some private tool or whatever); or (b) using SVNKit *in* your own (non-open-source) code which you want to distribute. Note that the license only comes into effect when you *distribute* as well (a common misunderstanding of GPL-like licences)--- see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SvnClientAdapter](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html) is a high level Java subversion library that is Apache licensed and can use multiple low-level implementations depending on your needs. It is the library that Subclipse uses.

Comment: It looks like Javahl and SvnClientAdapter both use SVNKit. So would I be able to use these without paying the licensing fee? And, if so, is there any documentation on how to use SVNClientAdapter?

Comment: SvnClientAdapter can use SVNKit, or it can use JavaHL or the svn command line client, and it is Apache licensed so you do not need to pay any licensing fees.  JavaHL does not use SVNKit, it uses JNI to wrap the native C subversion library.  I am not aware of any documentation on how to use the client adapter, but you can find examples via Google.

Comment: @michael-greene Not sure that is true, see my comment at simbo1905's answer.

Comment: @PureSpider Which part are you not sure about being true?  I see that in the comment on simbo1905's answer SVNKit has a strictly viral license when redistributed, including as part of another piece of software, but nowhere in my answer or comment do I speak to redistribution of SVNKit.  If you're willing to abide by SVNKit's terms, you can use it with SvnClientAdapter, but if you're not willing to you can still use one of the other SvnClientAdapter implementations (JavaHL or the svn executable wrapper, both of which are permissively licensed).

Comment: @michael-greene That is true, I thought you were talking about how SVNKits license doesn't apply when using SvnClientAdapter (which is Apache licensed).

Answer (score 1):

The question does not state "reuse" or "link to" or any other aspect which suggests that the person wants to embed SVNKit in their software. Taken literally "I'd use SVNKit" as a tool then the question is misinformed. Reading the license for SVNKit it says that it is free to use without restriction:

http://svnkit.com/licensing/index.html

Specifically it says that if you can only redistribute svnkit as a *part of your software* if your software is itself opensource. That is like all the GNU developer tools and compilers which come with the GPL license; those have been for decades to build closed source software at major corporates which take the license very seriously. So long a*s you are not embedding the code of the tool in your own product* there is no problem with just using the tool for the purposes of making closed source software.

This is a common misconception about SVNKit which I was confused about hence my answer.

Comment: This is not true.
The compilers you are mentioning are themselves GPL but you don't actually use them IN you project (as libraries or such), you use them to build your project.
Furthermore, the license that SVNKit uses exlicitly says: "[...] Redistributions in any form must be accompanied by information on **how to obtain complete source code for the software that uses SVNKit and any accompanying software that uses the software that uses SVNKit.** [...]", see: http://www.svnkit.com/license.html

Comment: Agree with PureSpider: this answer is a fundamental misunderstanding of open source licensing, and the difference between using open-source-licensed *tools* to produce things and distributing open-source-licensed *libraries* with a product/library. See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF

Comment: The above comments seem to be deliberately misunderstanding the question for sport. The question says "use" which has to be taken in literal form (e.g. simply installed into eclipse to use as a tool much like a compiler). This is no implication of "reuse" as part of the software in the question. This is a very common question about SVNKit which I was confused about until i read the license.

Comment: @simbo1905 OK, yes, I agree that the question could be interpreted that way; i.e., "I'm using SVNKit to perform SVN operations on some (non open-source) code I wrote." (I had a strong feeling that the question wasn't phrased like that when I left the downvote, but I assume the lack of edit history doesn't lie!) I'll reverse the downvote if I'm able to (suspect not)...

Comment: Added comment to the question to that effect. On reflection, I think the two interpretations are (to me) about 50:50 in terms of which is likeliest to capture what the OP meant.

Comment: OK, I've reversed the downvote (it goes -1 to +1 which is interesting; i.e., either it doesn't 'know' that I was a downvoter, or it views it as me changing my downvote to an upvote). Anyway, an upvote is fine since I agree that you answer one interpretation of the question.